# adding a branch to a remote repository and pushing - workflow

Tags: git, github, command-line, version-control, git-remote

Can somebody help me figure out the steps I'd take to accomplish the following:

add a branch to a remote repository for an existing project and commit and push to that branch.

I'm, for some reason, overcomplicating GIT and having a tough time finding resources to help me figure out just what I want to do.

I'd like to do this all through terminal.

Would I first connect to the remote repo, then create a branch, then git init on that branch?

Once I have finished a certain implementation, would I then, using terminal again, connect to that branch, 'check out', commit, and push? And from then on out, every change I make is just a push?

There's currently just a master branch, so I want my local project to actually contain all the code from that master (which it should anyway since I'm branching off of it), and just push my changes to the branch as needed...

Answer (score 0):

Just push the branch, it will be created in the remote if it doesn't already exist.

For instance:

```
git clone http://myRemoteRepo
git checkout -b myNewBranch # Create a new local branch since it's what you seem to want
#do some dev
git commit -am "My awesome commit"
git push origin myNewBranch # It will create myNewBranch in myRemoteRepo
```

To answer the questions in your comment:

- Once you checked out a branch, as long as you don't checkout anything else, you'll remain on that branch. You can check the branch you're currently in using `git branch`
- when we use `git push origin myNewBranch` we're actually saying to Git: "push to the remote you know as 'origin'. I ask you to push from my local branch 'myNewBranch', and to push to the remote branch 'myNewBranch'"

So, it's not what you checked-out which has an impact on what you're pushing

---

> then git init on that branch

Note that this has no sense: you don't `git init` a branch: you init a new repo. Then you can create branch on this repo.

Moreorever, you usually only `init` once, at the very beginning of the project. ie: when you want to clone a repo locally, well, you just clone it, you don't need to `git init` anything.

Comment: I'm literally starting from square one and trying to figure out if my thought process makes any sense. While this may answer the original question, I'm trying to find out more about the flow of things and the actual steps taken to achieve the desired end result.

Comment: made an edit to my last paragraph. My mistake on that end, I made it seem like I wanted to push to the master.

Comment: Assuming I'm going to be using xcode for this project: I clone the original repo and successfully create a branch called BB and check out to that branch. Do I simply open up the cloned repo, start doing some work on the existing project, and commit and push my changes? Does checking out into the branch earlier on terminal persist as a preference, meaning that all pushes will go into that branch from then on out? Sorry to keep asking but your answers are helping me get closer!

Answer (score 0):

1. First git clone your remote repo`git clone XXXXX`
2. Get to the point where you want to do work `git reset --HARD <whereYouWantToStart>`
3. Possibly make your own branch `git checkout -b yourBranchName`
4. git add/git commit your changes
5. Either merge your work back to some development or master branch `git checkout master;git merge yourBranchName'
6. Push your results back `git push origin master' or 'git push origin yourBranchName`

Comment: Also, you might want to read a reference on Git before you get started. The good news is that there is tons of free tutorials, for instance, http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control. The bad news is that you are going to have to invest some time (maybe 1/2 a day or reading) to get up and going and understand more.

Comment: BTW, Code School has a free class entitled "Try Git" https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git to get you through the basics. Its probably one of the easiest ways to get up to speed. In addition, it looks like they also have some follow on git glasses that are for pay.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only one developing this repo:

1. Clone repo that you want to develop locally. `git clone http://repoURL`
2. Create a new branch (locally) on which to make changes. `git checkout -b newBranchName`
3. Make changes locally to files.
4. Add files to list of changes to commit. `git add file1 file2 fileEtc`
5. Commit changes locally. `git commit -a -m"Message explaining changed files, which will show up as part of commit on github after pushing."`
6. Push changes to your repo on github. `git push origin newBranchName`
7. Now you'll have a new branch on github, which you can merge with your master branch when you're ready.

Note: Before committing, you can run `git status` to see untracked files. You can also type `git branch` to see all of your branches, and which one you are currently on.

To delete a branch: `git -d branchName` (Cannot be on that branch when deleting.)

To switch branches (among pre-existing branches): `git checkout branchName`